# MongoDB error whilte connecting

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I am following a tutorial on MongoDB, but when I try to run         `mongod`, this is what I get:

```
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod
2018-02-19T16:10:39.918+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6980 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-7H2SJ95
2018-02-19T16:10:39.919+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-02-19T16:10:39.919+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
2018-02-19T16:10:39.919+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
2018-02-19T16:10:39.919+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2018-02-19T16:10:39.919+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-02-19T16:10:39.920+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-02-19T16:10:39.920+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-02-19T16:10:39.920+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2018-02-19T16:10:39.920+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-02-19T16:10:39.920+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-02-19T16:10:39.920+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-02-19T16:10:39.920+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2018-02-19T16:10:39.920+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-02-19T16:10:39.922+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100`
```

Could anyone help?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `C:\data\db\ not found` !!!!!!

Comment: Please search before you ask. This has been asked many times already.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `db` folder inside `C:\data` as your `database` and `collections` will be using this location by default to save the data.